# python bleach linkify is removing my safe attributes

Tags: python

I'm using Angular.  Angular has the ability to write custom html tags. I'm trying to post a custom tag, run bleach to clean any unwanted tags, and then retrieve the sanitized version of text and render it.

The issue I'm having is bleaches linkify is auto escaping my custom tags. I don't know how to turn this behavior off.

My code is as follows

```
def _set_target(attrs, new=False):
    p = urlparse.urlparse(attrs['href'])
    if p.netloc != settings.FOO_URL:
        attrs['target'] = '_blank'
        attrs['class'] = 'external'
    else:
        attrs.pop('target', None)
    return attrs


def clean_text(text):
    """
    Sanitizes text for dangerous html and creates anchor tags out of
    parsed links for the community posts.
    """
    bleach.ALLOWED_TAGS.append('user')
    bleach.ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES['user'] = ['full_name', 'user']
    cleaned_text = bleach.clean(text)
    linkified_text = bleach.linkify(cleaned_text, (_set_target,))
    return linkified_text
```

My text input is:

```
   <user full_name="Izeni admin" user="izeni"></user> afafaf
```

The return value is

```
   "&lt;user full_name=\"Izeni admin\" user=\"izeni\"&gt;&lt;/user&gt; afafaf"
```

I need the output to be the same as the input on these tags:

```
<user full_name="Izeni admin" user="izeni"></user> afafaf
```

And be auto escaped on other tags, (e.g scripts)

For example:
A user could enter in:

```
 <script>console.log('hello world')</script>
```

If ran through this the out put should be

```
&lt;script&gt;console.log('hello world')&lt;/script&gt;
```

Which it is.

The bleach clean is working as expected. It is not escaping my tags. The linkify is. Does any one know how to turn this behavior off?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Expected out put is <user full_name="Izeni admin" user="izeni"></user> afafaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for [`clean`](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach/blob/master/bleach/__init__.py#L98) can be helpful here.  Basically, `clean` builds a `bleach.BleachSanitizer` class (which is a subclass of `html5lib.HTMLSanitizer`) and uses that as the as the tokenizer.  `linkify` allows you to pass your own tokenizer, so you can just build the tokenizer the same way that `clean` does.

```
import bleach

def my_linkify(content,
               tags=bleach.ALLOWED_TAGS, 
               allowed_attributes=bleach.ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES, 
               styles=bleach.ALLOWED_STYLES,
               strip=False,
               strip_comments=False):
    class Tokenizer(bleach.BleachSanitizer):
        allowed_elements = tags
        allowed_attributes = attributes
        allowed_css_properties = styles
        strip_disallowed_elements = strip
        strip_html_comments = strip_comments
    return bleach.linkify(content, tokenizer=Tokenizer)
```

Of course, you *could* always pass additional keyword arguments through to `bleach.linkify` -- And you don't really need the extra function `my_linkify` -- You could just build the `Tokenizer` at the module level if it is meant to be in multiple places throughout the application.

---

As an aside, I would recommend that you don't mutate `bleach.ALLOWED_TAGS`, etc.  Often, names written in ALL_CAPS indicates that they are meant to be constants (and if you mutate them, then you violate that assumption).  A better approach would be to mutate a copy and pass it through.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) to `unescape` before the fuction return. **DEMO:**

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> h= HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape( "&lt;user full_name=\"Izeni admin\" user=\"izeni\"&gt;&lt;/user&gt; afafaf")
u'<user full_name="Izeni admin" user="izeni"></user> afafaf'
>>> h.unescape("&lt;script&gt;console.log('hello')&lt;/script&gt;") 
u"<script>console.log('hello')</script>"
>>>
```

Comment: h.unescape("&lt;script&gt;console.log('hello')&lt;/script&gt;") ==  u"<script>console.log('hello')</script>"

Comment: I can't see any difference between the output and expected output.>_<

Comment: lol This difference is I'm putting in <> tags and it's sanatizing them to be &lt; and &gt; on my custom tags. This is fine for script tags, because their unsafe.

Comment: More confused about what you want. Just tell me the `difference between the output and expected output` maybe helpful.

Comment: You'r solution is fine. If it didn't undo my sanitize. I'm purposefully escaping certain tags. That would undo this escape.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example on `purposefully escaping certain tags`

Comment: K added it to the question. Ty for your help btw.